# validate input max value with another variable

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

Hello everyone I'm using asp.net mvc to build this page.

Currently there's a DataTable building a HTML table sorta looks like this, it has an  that sets the max value of the current input on click.

However I would like to verify that setting up the max value of that input does NOT go over the Max_ActualValue which is in another codeblock

```
<input type="hidden" id="Max_ActualValue" name="Max_ActualValue" value="@max_overall_value">
<table id="tableID" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No. 0</th>
            <th>No. 1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@{
    foreach(System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows){
        string value1 = dr["value1"].ToString();
        int value2 = dr["value2"];
        <tr>
          <td align="center">@value1</td>
          <td>
          <input type="number" name="someAwesomeNAME" id="someAwesomeID" min="0" max="@value2" value="" step="0.01" style="width: 100px" title="Currency" pattern="^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$">
          <a class="set-max">&#9745;</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
}
</table>

<script>
    var valorMontoMaximo = document.getElementById('Pago_ValorActual').value;   
    var valorActualMontoMaximo = valorMontoMaximo;
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.set-max');
    buttons.forEach(function (button) {
        button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            var input = event.currentTarget.parentElement.querySelector('input[type="number"]');   
            var montoAplicado = input.max;
            var validarMontoAplicado = valorActualMontoMaximo - montoAplicado;            
            if (validarMontoAplicado > 0) {
                valorActualMontoMaximo = validarMontoAplicado;
                input.value = input.max; 
            } else {
                swal({ title: "Not enough value.", text: "Please apply the value manually." });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

SO, above code works with this variable called `Max_ActualValue` which is taken from another DataTable, quick example is

```
<input type="hidden" id="Max_ActualValue" name="Max_ActualValue" value="@actual_Value">
```

Now lets make it super clear, I can't find a way to avoid going over `Max_ActualValue` inside my inputs because it should be already setup to max value of `value2` value taken out of the table.

How can I the both validations? i.e

I have Max_ActualValue = 1,000.00

And I have some rows that looks like this, how can I avoid going over 1,000.00 while still being allowed to click on set-max without overloading the 1,000.00 available?

Like if I use 100, there'll be 900 left and I can't go over 900 nor 1000 if I did not spent them cant be sure if Im explaining myself :( hope to get some guidance

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Max Value = 1000</h1>
<h2>HTML Table</h2>
 <input type="hidden" name="Max_ActualValue" id="Max_ActualValue" value="1000" />
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Max</th>
    <th>Apply</th>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>100</td>
   <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" value="" step="0.01" style="width: 100px" title="Currency" pattern="^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$"><a class="set-max">&#9745;</a> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>200</td>
       <td><input type="number" min="0" max="200" value="" step="0.01" style="width: 100px" title="Currency" pattern="^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$"><a class="set-max">&#9745;</a> </td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>300</td>   <td><input type="number" min="0" max="300" value="" step="0.01" style="width: 100px" title="Currency" pattern="^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$"><a class="set-max">&#9745;</a> </td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>400</td>   <td><input type="number" min="0" max="400" value="" step="0.01" style="width: 100px" title="Currency" pattern="^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$"><a class="set-max">&#9745;</a> </td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>500</td>   <td><input type="number" min="0" max="500" value="" step="0.01" style="width: 100px" title="Currency" pattern="^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$"><a class="set-max">&#9745;</a> </td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>600</td>   <td><input type="number" min="0" max="600" value="" step="0.01" style="width: 100px" title="Currency" pattern="^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$"><a class="set-max">&#9745;</a> </td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
var valorMontoMaximo = document.getElementById('Max_ActualValue').value;   
var valorActualMontoMaximo = valorMontoMaximo;
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.set-max');
buttons.forEach(function (button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        var input = event.currentTarget.parentElement.querySelector('input[type="number"]');            
        //input.value = input.max; 
        var montoAplicado = input.max;
        var validarMontoAplicado = valorActualMontoMaximo - montoAplicado;            
        if (validarMontoAplicado > 0) {
            valorActualMontoMaximo = validarMontoAplicado;
            input.value = input.max; 
        } else {
            alert('OVERFLOW');
        }
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As I know, first you have set a max value. Then you want to validate that summary all input rows in the table not greater max value, right?

Comment: I already added an update that does that but how do I allocate the correct autofill value with set-max ?